# Чёткость изображения

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения

И так, диспозиция следующая:
Есть  Image (контрол) размером 100 на 100
В качестве сорса изображения установлено изображение 100 на 100. Двухцветное (чёрный и белый без оттенков)
Масштабирование сорса изображения установленно в Uniform.

В рантайме перевожу Image в BitMap и сохраняю в файл следующим кодом:

```
 int width = (int)image.ActualWidth;
            int height = (int)image.ActualHeight;

            RenderTargetBitmap rtb =
            new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Default);
            rtb.Render(image);


            BmpBitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            encoder.Save(ms);
            ms.Position = 0;

            Bitmap  CurentPrintLabelImg = new Bitmap(ms);
            CurentPrintLabelImg.Save("Test.bmp");
```

В итоге ожидаю, что на выходе получу изображение размером 100 на 100 абсолютно идентичное сорсу. Но получаю изображение с градациями серого по границам чёрных областей. (выглядит как размытие)

К тому же заметил что image.ActualWidth и image.ActualHeight меньше 100 (~99 и 98)

Как добиться совпадения исходного и выходного изображения и почему контрол масштабируется в рантайме?

Comment: Эээ, что вы делаете? Почему вы сохраняете представление, а не модель? Сохраняйте ваш `Image.Source`.

Comment: @VladD: я понятное дело слегка упростил проблему. Я могу заменить image на канву в которой таких имеджей будет штук 5 + текст + что-нибудь от руки нарисованное юзверем и всё это мне в картинку нужно будет сохранить без ресайза, перевода в градации серого и потери качества...

Comment: Всё равно это как-то неправильно. Вы пытаетесь сохранять View, а вам стоит по идее все эти объекты иметь в модели, и сохранять в ней. Чтобы (а) не вешать UI на время сохранения, (б) не зависеть от особенностей рендеринга, (в) ну и вообще так вроде правильнее.

Comment: ок. Допустим. У меня есть в модели картинки, текст и path'ы которым юзверь что-то там нарисовал. Теперь всё это дело мне нужно скомпоновать так, как оно выглядело на экране в канве и сохранить в картинку... Рисовать всё это черед Graphics ?

Comment: Ну или через `WritableBitmap`, `Drawing`, `RenderTargetBitmap` и всё такое. Типа этого: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14387686/276994. Тут вы уж точно контролируете все размеры, и можете отделить эту часть от представления